# quick access pinned folders dissappearing and changing

Tags: windows-10

My quick access pinned folders are disappearing and other folders get added in. For example I don't need quick access to documents.  But that's what my quick access folders had pinned.  All of the pins I made were lost.  Might be something with unzip as everytime this has happened I had unzipped a file.

Comment: Did you try to fault check to make sure it is happening only when you're unzipping a file? or is it something you've hypothesised? I understand it could be a frustrating issue you're experiencing however for anyone to provide you with a solid solution you will have to make sure you [ask the best possible question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) you could regarding your issue.

Comment: No I haven't proved zip causes this.  For all I know someone in tech support could be doing this.

Comment: Have you tried going into the File Explorer's Folder Options and making sure the 'Show recently used files in Quick access' and 'Show frequently used folders in Quick Access' are unchecked?

Comment: I did uncheck after the fact.  But I like the frequently used folders option so that is a deal breaker fix if it even works.

Answer (score 0):

The File Explorer automatic [Quick Access](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4027032/windows-pin-remove-and-customize-in-quick-access) pinning behaviour is determined through 2 settings in Folder Options.

## To check/change Quick Access settings

1. Open **File Explorer** and go into the **Folder Options**.
2. In the **General** tab, in the **Privacy** section review the check boxes for the 2 settings;

   - '**Show recently used files in Quick access**',
   - and, '**Show frequently used folders in Quick access**'.
3. Click **OK** to apply any changes or **Cancel** to exit without applying any changes.

Additionally, you can reset/clear any File Explorer history by clicking the **Clear** button in Folder Options. This will remove all automatic pins from Quick Access but it preserves your manually pinned folders/files.